# RichFaces: c:forEach inside a4j:region

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces

I have a `a4j:region`

Why `c:forEach` with `rich:tab`s inside is not rendered inside richfaces container tags(`a4j:region`, `rich:panel`, etc)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`c:forEach` is not executed in the right life-cycle for your usage, here you can get more info about that : [c:forEach vs ui:repeat in Facelets](https://rogerkeays.com/jsf-c-foreach-vs-ui-repeat)